# What is the word for someone calling something bad, but then that person does the same thing?

Tags: single-word-requests

I really want to know because it occurs a lot with the people I hang out with.

I would do something "bad" and get in trouble, or get called out for it, but then the people who had a negative response to what I did would do the same thing as if they forgot it was bad.

Answer (score 1):

This is called

> [hypocrisy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypocrisy) behavior that contradicts what one claims to believe or feel (Merriam-Webster).

It is not the same thing as lying, which is false statement of belief. It is a very particular form of inconsistency, where one proclaims (usually) certain acts to be virtuus, and then acting the opposite way.

Comment: I did think it was being hypocritical, but it the meaning fell into wearing a mask- believing or act with higher standards while being the opposite, I was wondering if I can find something of behaving in a way where you are "shaming" someone for doing something, but then you would do the something. Like you get the it's only okay if I do it vibe.